# What does the "total" member of the "loadstart" event of XMLHttpRequest contain?

Tags: javascript

According to [this documentation](https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/#firing-events-using-the-progressevent-interface) the `XMLHttpRequest` can generate an event `loadstart` of the type `ProgressEvent`.
This type of event contains several members, one of them is the read-only property `total`.

**QUESTION**: What does the `total` member contain for the  `loadstart` event?

Note, that in the code below, the `e.total` returned for the `loadstart` event is very different from the `e.total` returned for the `load` event, despite the fact that they both refer to the length of the same data structure during the same operation.

```
function SendData(formdata) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.upload.addEventListener("loadstart", function(e) {
        console.log(e.total);  // What does this mean ?
    }, false);

    xhr.upload.addEventListener("load", function(e) {
        console.log(e.total);  // Different value returned
    }, false);


    xhr.open("POST", "receive.php");
    xhr.send(formdata);
}
```

BTW: For the same formdata, the value in `ProgressEvent.total` is different between FireFox and Chrome.  The difference is huge.

The [documentation](https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/#firing-events-using-the-progressevent-interface) states that:

> "To fire a progress event named `e` at a target, given `transmitted` and
>   `length`, means to fire an event named `e` at a target, using `ProgressEvent`,
>   with the `loaded` attribute initialized to `transmitted`, and if `length` is
>   not 0, with the `lengthComputable` attribute initialized to true and the
>   `total` attribute initialized to `length`."

Therefore, whatever the `length` represents, it must be **the same** for ALL events that refer to **the same** data structure and **the same** operation, such as the one performed by `XMLHttpRequest.send()`.

And since the attribute `total` == `length` when `lengthComputable`== `true`, what logically follows is that the attribute `total` of all `ProgressEvents` referring to the **same data** structure and operation, must be **the same**, too,
... when`lengthComputable`== `true`.

Answer (score 0):

The event for that callback is a [`ProgressEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ProgressEvent). Apparently, the `e.total` value is an opaque representation of how much "work" needs to be done, and `e.loaded` tells how much of that work has already been completed. Since an XHR request may be timed differently depending on browser, their classification of what a unit of work is differs.

You're expected to do something like calculate a percentage to get more meaning out of these numbers. For example: `e.loaded / e.total`. There's also an `e.lengthComputable` property, since in some cases it can't be computed how long progress will take (perhaps if there's no `Content-Length` header, for example).

Comment: The specs are beyond vague as to what those values are supposed to mean; it clearly seems to be intended as a browser-dependent feature.

Comment: I cannot agree with that because `e.total` returned for the `loadstart` event is very different from the `e.total` returned for the `load` event.

Comment: @GeorgeRobinson [this is the best description I can find in the spec](https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/#firing-events-using-the-progressevent-interface)

Comment: @GeorgeRobinson Perhaps, whether browsers implement the specifications as written or not is a matter to take up with the browser vendors, not with someone answering your question voluntarily on Stack Overflow....

Comment: @Heretic:  I will once I get an answer from one of you, that the implementation of `loadstart.total` is buggy.

Comment: It's not buggy. The spec leaves the usage up to individual implementations.

Comment: @GeorgeRobinson How would we know which is correct? As Pointy pointed out (sorry) the specs are vague as to what exactly the algorithm should be. Put another way, if the implementation is up to the browser vendors, and you are unhappy with the browser vendors' implementations, bring it up with the browser vendors.

Comment: @Amy.  Does the spec leave the **consistency** between `loadstart.total` and `load.total` up to individual implementations, too ?

Comment: @GeorgeRobinson The spec says nothing about consistency between vendors.  If it did, the spec wouldn't be leaving it up to the vendors, it would clearly define the expected behavior.  It isn't doing that, because its up to the vendors.

Comment: I see nothing about consistency in the meaning of `total` among progress events either, so that does seem to be up to implementations.

Comment: If the spec expects implementations to be *consistent*, it will define *how*.

Comment: IMO the spec does define it because it describes what the members of the `ProgressEvent` are supposed to be set to: QUOTE:"To fire a progress event named e at target, given `transmitted` and `length`, means to fire an event named e at target, using `ProgressEvent`, with the `loaded` attribute initialized to `transmitted`, and if `length` is not 0, with the `lengthComputable` attribute initialized to `true` and the `total` attribute initialized to `length`.".  Therefore. since both of these `ProgressEvent`s refer to the same `XMLHttpRequest`, both `total`s should be set to **the same** `length`

Comment: The point is that the spec does not define how implementations populate those properties.  The length of what?  Transmitted what?  The spec does not define, in specific terms, where those values are supposed to come from.  Maybe one browser includes the size of the headers, and the other doesn't?  Or maybe one considers the gzip-compressed size?  It is intentionally vague, leaving the actual behavior up to individual implementations.

Comment: @Amy  Neither the units nor the data structure, that they pertain to, are at the core of this discrepancy. Whatever they are, they pertain to **the same** data structure, thus the `total` member must contain the length of this data structure if `lengthComputable` is set to `true`.  For ALL `ProgressEvent`s.

Comment: @Amy Also, `transmitted` in reference to `XMLHttpRequest.send()` is pretty unambiguous.  Your suggestion that only the RFC2388 headers are `transmitted` when sending a 1MB file encoded as `multipart/form-data` by `XMLHttpRequest.send()`, is illogical.  The same goes for the `total` quantity to be send/transmitted, which cannot vary between events that refer to **the same** data structure and **the same** sending operation, such as the one performed by `XMLHttpRequest.send()`.